# Get number after number in PHP

Tags: php

I doubt if it is possible but I'm looking for the following:

E.g. `$number`'s value is 1, can I get the next number, in this case 2, to be the value of another variable, e.g. `$newnumber`?

I prefer to do this in SQLite, so the numbers are stored in a database.

Comment: you mean,you have to increment number,is it?

Comment: `$newnumber = $number++;` anything is possible.

Comment: Something like `$newnumber = $number + 1;`?

Comment: will the numbers always increment by one or are you looking to determine a pattern and increment accordingly?

Comment: @MrHunter You're actually incrementing `$number`, and `$newnumber` would be set to `1`. Try it out.

Comment: @MrHunter This doesn't work.`$number = 1;
$newnumber = $number++;
echo $newnumber;` outputs 1.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards My bad, try `$number++; echo $number;` or `$newnumber = $number; $newnumber++; echo $newnumber;`

Comment: @MrHunter Both of your new codes work, thanks.

Comment: The answer of @smistry is now the accepted answer. I was thinking too complicated - now I remember how easy PHP can be ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try: `$newnumber = ((int) ($number)) + 1`, if this is for a primary key though just set the column to auto increment

Comment: Sorry, I did `echo $number` `echo $newnumber`, without spaces, so the output was 21. This works!

Comment: +1 for the type juggling, have you ran this updated code to check it will not throw errors?

Comment: @DarylGill The new code works as well, `$number = 1;
$newnumber = ((int) ($number)) + 1;
echo $newnumber;` outputs 2 like supposed to.

Comment: @WilliamDavidEdwards Nice nice, i'd recommend using the updated code as type juggling to force the result/variable type to integer

Answer (score 1):

```
$newnumber=$number+1;
```

I think it can't get more simpler than that.

Comment: This doesn't work. `$number` ends up being `2`. And `$newnumber` ends up being `1`. Don't take shortcuts like that if you don't understand how self-incrementing works.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't had to use incrementing or self-incrementing for a long time, so I forgot it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the larger scope of what you're trying to accomplish, my suggestion would be to use the increment operator in PHP.

Original answer:

Something like:

```
$number = 1;
$newNumber = $number++;
```

Correct answer (above gives wrong result):

```
$number = 1;
$number++;
$newNumber = $number;
```

From there you can do whatever you want with the second variable.

Comment: I posted this answer from my android app, it seems the formatting for code didn't carry over, my apologies.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/dc57caa10a50fd51529cdd5c5915915872acb193

Comment: @DavidMorin Updated your answers body to include the code tags, but as commented on another answer before the poster updated code: *This doesn't work. $number ends up being 2. And $newnumber ends up being 1. Don't take shortcuts like that if you don't understand how self-incrementing works.*

Comment: Three other people seem to have fallen for this common mistake. `$variable++` is **self-incrementing**. When PHP parses this, it sees that `$newnumber` needs to be assigned, assigns the value of `$number`, _then_ self-increments `$number` by 1.

Comment: Yes that's right my mistake. Should I leave the answer so others can see the problem or edit it and correct it?

Comment: Yes, to prevent others from making the same mistake :)

Comment: Tried to edit to make my mistake clear and the correct way clear but I think my phone is causing an issue with updates. If someone else doesn't fix it first I'll fix it when back at my desk.